# sed / awk complex line replacement

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I want to replace thousands lines like this, but I'm having a hard time trying to make it work, also I have 2 variables $time and $date condition, to not make it global.:

Example: `<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>`

To replace: `<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>`

I tried with sed:

```
sed -i '<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST \/ 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00<\/v><\/row>.*/<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST \/ 1594050300 --> <row><v>NaN<\/v><\/row>/' dump_teste.xml
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `<'

Also with awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1' tmp.txt
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                     ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                               ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                         ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                      ^ syntax error
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                ^ unterminated string
    awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
    awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                ^ syntax error
```

or

```
awk '{sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1' tmp.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                               ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(/<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>1.9933333333e+00</v></row>/,"<!-- 2020-07-08 12:00:00 WEST / 1594206000 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>")}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
```

Comment: You need an xml parser for this.

Comment: What about `sed -E 's/<v>([^<]*)/<v>NaN/g'` ?

Comment: is a good choice, but I have 2 variables to pass before $date and $time in that specifics lines I want the change, not in all 1 milion lines of the file :)

Comment: Then `sed -E '/2020-07-06 16:45:00/s/<v>([^<]*)/<v>NaN/g'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your need below is a command to replace number with NAN in file considering all lines that fall in time range irrespective of order in which lines appear.

```
set date from and till variables and then below command

while IFS= read -r in; do out="$(echo "$in" | awk '{print $2}')" && outtime="$(echo "$in" | awk '{print $3}')" && sed -i "/"$out" "$outtime"/ s/<v>.*<\/v>/<v>NAN<\/v>/" dumpteste.xml; done <<< "$(sort -k3 -k4 -k5 dumpteste.xml | awk -v date="$date" -v from="$from" -v till="$till" '$2 == date && $3 >= from && $3 <= till' | tac)"
```

Example of above command

```
cat dumpteste.xml         #original file
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:47:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 17:47:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:48:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 17:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --><row<v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>



date=2020-07-06
from=16:45:00
till=17:45:00
```

```
 Output  
cat dumpteste.xml      #after change

<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NAN</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:47:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NAN</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 17:47:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NAN</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:48:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NAN</v></row>
<!-- 2020-07-06 17:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>NAN</v></row>
<!-- 2020-08-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>
```

See for dates 2020-07-06, when time range 16:45:00-17:45:00 is provided lines with time 16:45,16:48,16:47,17:45 are changed.
For time 16:45 but date 2020-08-06 it did not changed as date not matches.

Also if you need to enter date in range then define four variables: date, enddate, from, till. And execute below command

```
date=2020-07-06
enddate=2020-08-06
from=16:45:00
till=17:45:00
while IFS= read -r in; do out="$(echo "$in" | awk '{print $2}')" && outtime="$(echo "$in" | awk '{print $3}')" && sed -i "/"$out" "$outtime"/ s/<v>.*<\/v>/<v>NAN<\/v>/" du*; done <<< "$(sort -k3 -k4 -k5 du* | awk -v date="$date" -v from="$from" -v till="$till" -v enddate="$enddate" '$2 >= date && $2 <= enddate && $3 >= from && $3 <= till' | tac)"
```

Above command will help you in your task of changing the values provided with date and time in range
Hope this is enough?

Shorter Version:
1). With time range

```
date=2020-07-06 && from=16:45:00 && till=17:45:00 && gawk -i inplace -v date="$date" -v from="$from" -v till="$till" '$2 == date && $3 >= from && $3 <= till {gsub(/<v>[^<]*/, "<v>nan<")}1' dumpteste.xml
```

2). With both date and time range

```
date=2020-07-06 && from=16:45:00 && till=17:45:00 && enddate=2020-08-06 && awk -v date="$date" -v from="$from" -v till="$till" -v enddate="$enddate" '$2 >= date && $2 <= enddate && $3 >= from && $3 <= till {gsub(/<v>[^<]*/, "<v>nan<")}1' dumpteste.xml
```

Comment: I have added another command to answer that uses date in range and time in range. If you find it useful clcik on check icon on left of answer to accept it

Answer (score 2):

The command you are trying is not having s option thats why it gives error.

```
sed -i 's/<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST \/ 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00<\/v><\/row>.*/<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST \/ 1594050300 --> <row><v>NaN<\/v><\/row>/g' dumpteste.xml
```

or

```
sed -i 's/<v>.*<\/v>/<v>NAN<\/v>/g' dumpteste.xml
```

You are having two variable $date and $time and want to match lines having those variables and then apply sed. Do following:

```
sed "/"$date" "$time" .*<\/row>/ s/<v>.*<\/v>/<v>NAN<\/v>/g" dumpteste.xml
```

In above command if line is

````
<!-- 2020-07-06 16:45:00 WEST / 1594050300 --> <row><v>5.0000000000e+00</v></row>```
And date and time variable are
date='2020-07-06' time='16:45:00' 
then only line containg that date and time will be edited by sed.


Did it solved your problem?
````

Comment: Well Almost, it works for specific $date and $time.

Comment: If I have the following: 
time_from='16:45:00'
time_till='17:45:00'
date='2020-07-06'  still possible with sed?

Comment: Thank you for all the effort !

Comment: from the original question: "I have 2 variables $time and $date", when did time split into a range?  Please do not change the question after it's answered.  It will confuse people when it will be referred later.

Comment: See another answer given below by me as per your needs that satisfy range and variables